# In Python what's the difference between using 'elif' statements vs. 'or' statements?

Tags: python

How are the two options different? I'm using some arbitrary code as an example but the question is general.

**Using 'or'**

```
if (passenger['Sex'] == 'female') or (passenger['Pclass'] == 1):
    predictions[passenger_id] = 1
else:
    predictions[passenger_id] = 0
```

**Using 'elif'**

```
if (passenger['Sex'] == 'female'):
    predictions[passenger_id] = 1
elif (predictions[passenger_id] = 1):
    predictions[passenger_id] = 1
else:
    predictions[passenger_id] = 0
```

Comment: Functionally, there is no difference. You are however, repeating yourself in option 2.

Comment: in ur case its seem ok , but using `or` and elif is different

Comment: The question isn't general - if you have a more complicated conditional and the cost of calculating the predicates is significant, `elif` or nested `if`'s may be the better option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first reduces code duplication. For example

```
s = 'd'
if s == 'a' or s == 'b' or s == 'c'... etc:
    print('Is alpha')
else:
    print('Not alpha')
```

As opposed to

```
s = 'd'
if s == 'a':
    print('Is alpha')  # repetition of same code
elif s == 'b':
    print('Is alpha')  # repetition of same code
elif s == 'c':
    print('Is alpha')  # repetition of same code
elif... etc:
    print('Is alpha')  # repetition of same code
else:
    print('Not alpha')
```

Note that the above is simply an example to get the point across, you could more pythonically do

```
if s.isalpha():
```

or

```
if s in string.ascii_lowercase:
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code snippet, there is no *functional* difference (at the end of your if-suite, you'll have the same result).  However, `or` allows you to only write the code in the branch one time which is more DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) -- And that's pretty much always a good thing.

In the general case, `elif` allows you to take *different* actions in different branches:

```
if (passenger['Sex'] == 'female'):
    do_thing_1()
elif (predictions['Pclass'] = 1):
    do_thing_2()
```

This can't be accomplished using `or`.

Comment: I'm assuming that the conditions in the original post were meant to be the same :-).

Answer (score 1):

You use `elif` when you want certain code to run under the condition that an earlier clause was `False` and this one is `True`, without re-evaluating **or respecifying** that earlier clause. Say that we want to give someone a grade based on their score. We could write it like this:

```
if score >= 90:
    grade = 'A'
if score < 90 and score >= 80: # not using: 80 <= score < 90, to make AND explicit
    grade = 'B'
if score < 80 and score >= 70:
    grade = 'C'
if score < 70 and score >= 60:
    grade = 'D'
else:
    grade = 'E'
```

As you can see, we're repeating the same information. If we want to make it so that to get an A, you need at least 95 points, we have to remember to change 90 into 95 twice, or face interesting bugs.

With `elif` you could rewrite it like this:

```
if score >= 90:
    grade = 'A'
elif score >= 80: # implicit condition: score < 90
    grade = 'B'
elif score >= 70: # implicit conditions: score < 90 and score < 80
    grade = 'C'
elif score >= 60: # implicit conditions: score < 90 and score < 80 and score < 70
    grade = 'D'
else:
    grade = 'E'
```

If you'd use `if` here instead of `elif`, everyone with at least 60 points would get a D. Just using `or` wouldn't work either:

```
if score >= 90 or score >= 80 or score >= 70 or score >= 60:
    grade = '?'
```

Hence, whether to use `elif` greatly depends on the similarities between the conditions and between the code that needs to be run if `True`.

In your case, the first option is better because you don't really care which of the two conditions was `True`; the very same needs to happen in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Building on mgilson's question, elif uses multiple branches, while the or statement evaluates everythin (seemingly) at once. In the case of

```
if a or b:
```

If 'b' takes significantly longer to evaluate than 'a', then using 'elif' is preferable.

```
if a:
  {code}
elif b:
  {code}
else:
  {other code}
```

Here 'b' is only evaluated if 'a' is found to be false, and therefore processing time is saved.

Note: I'm going off of my experience in C, C++, and basic. If python deals differently with 'or' statements, please let me know.

Comment: *"while the or statement evaluates everythin (seemingly) at once"* No it does not. The `or` statement will operate left to right, and short-circuits after the first evaluation of `True`. Similarly `and` behaves the same way and short-circuits after the first instance of `False`. In fact, since you mentioned you program in C and C++, this evaluation of `bool` logic is the same in those languages as well.